# SQL USER_NAME() windows authentication

Tags: sql-server

When I logged in sql management studio with windows authentication and I run

```
SELECT USER_NAME()
```

I see the result as dbo.

I would of thought that it would showed my user ....

I more looking at the explaination to as why it returns dbo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this instead

```
SELECT SUSER_NAME()
```

[USER_NAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188014.aspx): Returns a database user name from a specified identification number.

[SUSER_NAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187934.aspx): Returns the login identification name of the user.

Comment: I'm more interested in why it shows dbo. Do you know why it returns dbo?

Comment: @pdiddy - What did you expect it to return? This function will return a database user name - i.e. a value from `sysusers`.

Comment: Can I logged in as the database user into Management studio?

Comment: @pdiddy - When you login to the server you do so by giving the credentials of a server login. You don't login as a specific database user. These server logins are mapped to 0..n database users. If you are sysadmin you will automatically be mapped to the dbo user in all databases.

Comment: Great explaination. But In Server Roles for my logins, I do not see the sysadmin being checked but public.

Comment: Are you an administrator on the machine?

Comment: oh that would explain it. Thanks! so the only way would be to impersonate the database user.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

SELECT SUSER_SNAME()

Comment: @anish - Not quite. I said `SUSER_NAME`. Not sure how that it is different from `SUSER_SNAME`

Comment: mine is suser_sname; they appear interchangable.  Martin's answer was first should be considered correct.

Comment: I did a quick check in some SQL Server 2000 help and found the following comment: SUSER_NAME always returns NULL when used in Microsoft® SQL Server™ 2000. This system built-in function is included only for backward compatibility. Use SUSER_SNAME instead.

Comment: No mention of deprecation in [the SQL Server 2008 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187934.aspx). Wonder if they just decided to keep it.

Answer (score 2):

i had similar problem, the problem is due to the way user id is created.

choose the login id under security -> right click properties -> Server Roles. Ensure you click only "Public" no "sysadmin"